# Typos in API documentation

Tags: bug, status-completed, api-v2.2, documentation

From the [/posts documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/posts):

> Most applications should use the question or answer specific methods, but /posts is available for those rare cases where any activity is of **intereset**.

interes**e**t => interest

---

From [/posts/{ids}/suggested-edits](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/posts-on-suggested-edits) :

> Returns **suggsted** edits on the posts identified in ids.

suggsted => sugg**e**sted

---

From [/questions/{id}/flags/add](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/create-question-flag):

> Casts a flag (including **"**close votes) against the question identified by id.

The double quote isn't terminated, I assume "close votes" was meant.

---

From [/questions](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions):

> This is an **and** contraint,

(emphasis not mine; the typo is in the word con**s**traint)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These were just fixed in the latest build.